# How to solve this multivariate recurrence with Mathematica?

Tags: difference-equations

I would like to solve this recurrence relation:
$a_{m,n}=a_{m-1,n}+a_{m,n-1}$
with
$a_{0,0}=0, a_{m,0}=1, a_{0,n}=1$ for all $m\neq0$ and $n\neq0$

That's resembles the Tartaglia/Pascal's triangle,
[image]

the solution should be just the combinations...
$a_{m,n}=\binom{m+n}{n}$

But when I try to solve it with Mathematica

```
RSolve[{a[m, n] == a[-1 + m, n] + a[m, -1 + n],a[0, 0] == 0, 
a[m, 0] == 1, a[0, n] == 1}, a[m, n], {m, n}]
```

It just outputs the same input unevaluated.

What am I doing wrong?
Euler recurrence equation is also unsolved.

Comment: I don't think Mathematica supports bivariate (or multivariate in general) sequences in RSolve... See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751561/how-to-solve-this-multivariate-recurrence-with-mathematica .

Comment: That question is mine too. I wrote this new one because the older wasn't solved either. I expected Mathematica could solve it (It's supposed to be a very capable software).  Is any other CAS able to do it?